# Sharepoint 2010 Word Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, word

I have a document library with a couple of Word docs with Webparts in them. Each pull a hand full of field data from a Sharepoint list. One of the Word Docs is working fine and getting populated with the appropriate fields from the Sharepoint list, the other is not, only one of the 5 fields in the Document are getting populated. Is there a way of troubleshooting this kind of issue. Anyone have any suggestion on where to start. Not an expert on SP at all.

Answer (score -1):

If your word docs are setup correctly, you should see all fields you need populated in the Quick Parts > Document Property section of your word document. I'm pretty new to sharepoint as well but successfully used the following guide to get all my templates setup.

https://www.netwoven.com/2015/04/24/how-to-dynamically-create-and-populate-word-document-in-a-document-library-from-custom-list/

It is well documented and explained, and I hope it works for you. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have populated the word doc with the fields from the drop downs and have gotten one of about 5 fields to populate automatically. I'll take a look at the link and respond back.

Comment: From the directions on the link it appears that the Word Document is populated via a workflow, but I'm not able to follow where exactly this workflow is.

Comment: So determined that if I save the template document to my PC and upload it to the Document Folder the document is complete populated and works correctly. The document in question is copy as part of a custom workflow. It seems that the method of copying the template document to the document folder might be suspect.

Comment: // Do not overwrite if document file already exists    "CAR Document Sets/Lighting Enhancements 2018" Project.Title + " - " Document
                                    fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1} - {2}", myFolder.Url, docSet.Item["Name"].ToString(), fileRow.Name);
                                    fileRow.CopyTo(fileName, false);
                                    retValue = GetDocumentID(string.Format("{0} - {1}", docSet.Item["Name"].ToString(), fileRow.Name), docSet);

Comment: Does anyone know if the Webparts will populate from the SP List if the document template is copied over to a folder as opposed to be uploaded?